# VBA Traversing linked list results in run-time error 91

Tags: vba, excel

Linked list node CMLNode.

```
Option Explicit

Public key As Integer
Public pnext As CMLNode
```

Function to add values to list.

```
Option Explicit
Dim head As New CMLNode

Public Function Add()
    Dim curr As CMLNode
    Dim i As Integer


    Set curr = head
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set curr.pnext = New CMLNode
        Set curr = curr.pnext
        curr.key = i
    Next i

    Set curr = head
    While Not curr.pnext Is curr
        Set curr = curr.pnext
    Wend
End Function
```

I'm trying to implement a linked list in VBA. My problem is that whenever I get to the 6th iteration of the while loop (when it should break) I get a Run-time error '91' - Object variable or With block variable not set.

This function is obviously redundant, just a simple demonstration of my problem.

Comment: I'd move creation of the head (`New CMLNode`) into your function and not leave it as an assumed initialization at the module level. Also, which line is generating the error? It also looks like your linked list class is defaulting `.pnext` to point to itself when it just as easily could point to `nothing`. One last (important) point to mention is that VBA is not set up to effectively deal with pointers much beyond what you're doing. It's entirely possible to use a `Dictionary` or `Collection` as built-in collections for the same purpose.

Comment: The signature of `Add()` seems wrong. A sub (not really a function) to add something to the end of a linked list should take as arguments the list you are appending to and the value that you want to append.

Comment: @PeterT 
This line generates an error: 

`While Not curr.pnext Is curr`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I kept thinking of it from a java prespective where when you point to Null you've reached the end of the list. The code that Microsoft uses as a demo has the last node point to itself to signify the end of the list.

```
Public Function Add(key As Integer)
    Dim curr, prev As CMLNode
    Dim i As Integer


    Set curr = head
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set curr.pnext = New CMLNode
        Set curr = curr.pnext
        curr.key = i
    Next i
    Set curr.pnext = curr 'signify end of list

    Set curr = head
    While Not curr.pnext Is curr
        Set curr = curr.pnext
    Wend
End Function
```